# Take week number in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I need to get the week number in 2020 so that dates from 27th to 31st December are week 53 of 2021, 1st and 2nd January 2022 are week 1, and January 3rd is week 2.
If i use:

```
select  to_char(to_date('20220101','YYYYMMDD'), 'IW')::int >> 53
```

but if i use:

```
select  to_char(to_date('20220101','YYYYMMDD'), 'WW')::int >> 1
```

but

```
select  to_char(to_date('20220110','YYYYMMDD'), 'WW')::int >> also 1
```

I need:

```
select  to_char(to_date('20220101','YYYYMMDD'), 'WW')::int >> 1

select  to_char(to_date('20220102','YYYYMMDD'), 'WW')::int >> 1

select  to_char(to_date('20220103','YYYYMMDD'), 'WW')::int >> 2

select  to_char(to_date('20220110','YYYYMMDD'), 'WW')::int >> 3
```

UPDATE:
MSSQL has a function that allows you to get week numbers, but I can't figure out how it works, but it works

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(int, DATENAME(week, '20211231')), >> 53
    CONVERT(int, DATENAME(week, '20220101')), >> 1
    CONVERT(int, DATENAME(week, '20220102')), >> 1
    CONVERT(int, DATENAME(week, '20220103')), >> 2
    CONVERT(int, DATENAME(week, '20220110')) >> 3
```

Comment: 31st Dec must be in week 52 surely?

Comment: A week always has 7 days in every week numbering system I am aware of. You want week 53 to consist of 5 days and week 1 to consist of 2 days. There is no built-in function in Postgres that would achieve this, you will need to write your own.

Comment: @SolarMike i make a mistake - it must be 53 week

Comment: Isn't this achieved with through `date_part('week', '20211231')` etc.? I'm unfortunately not able to test myself currently.

Comment: @ErikBlomgren i tried, but its wrong:
`SELECT date_part('week', to_date('20211231', 'YYYYMMDD')) >> 52`
maybe I'm converting the date wrong, idk

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a special definition for week_of_year: the first week of the year begins on Jan 1 and subsequent weeks begin on each Sunday following. This yields a first week that will be between 1 and 7 days and, unexpectedly, each year having 53 or 54 weeks. The following function gives the desired week number for a given date: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=abb77fbce098884a8180d3a9025bd70f))

```
create or replace function week_in_year(date_in date) 
  returns integer
 language sql 
as $$
    with recursive 
         period(dt, edt) as 
          ( values ( date_trunc( 'year', date_in)::date, date_in)  )
      ,  week_period( wk, dt, edt) as 
         ( select 1, dt, edt
            from period
          union all 
          select case when extract(dow from (dt+1)) = 0
                      then wk+1
                      else wk
                 end
               , dt+1
               , edt
          from week_period
         where dt < edt
        ) 
    select wk from week_period 
      order by wk desc 
      limit 1; 
$$;
```

Comment: thak u so much!